# re-render when update this.props.location.query.somequery Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

render() function will fire when this.props.location.query.someQuery updated. But I do not want re-render the component when updated query.
The way I updated query is following:

```
this.props.location.query.someQuery = otherValue;
hashHistory.replace(this.props.location);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [react lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).

You should implement a method called `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

> Use this as an opportunity to return false when you're certain that the transition to the new props and state will not require a component update.

This method will be called each time React thinks your component should update, if you don't want it to re-render under certain conditions, check for those conditions and then return `false` in this function.